# Queries run in R Markdown much slower than queries run in R Console?

Tags: performance, r-markdown

I'm creating a report in R that estimates and plots the level of transmission of COVID19, and am finding that it runs MUCH more slowly in R Markdown than it does in the Console.  I am using RStudio for Mac v1.3.1093, and R v4.0.3.

This chart, which uses a Markov Chain Monte Carlo (MCMC) methodology to estimate infections and the level of spread, first obtains data showing new cases by day in the American state of Oklahoma.  This is very quick in both the Console and R Markdown.  The next part is the MCMC modelling, which is where the delays are coming.

I ran it this morning and it took 2.5 hours in R Markdown, compared to 30 minutes when running the query as an R Script in the Console.

I can't work out why it's SO much slower in the R Markdown version.  This becomes more important because, if I run the query at a county level (say, for 10 counties), then it models this 10 times, and would therefore take 10 times longer.

As a shortcut, I can simply run 2 queries, with the output of the modelling query being added into a bigger R Markdown query (e.g., by saving/reading in an RDS file).  However, I just can't understand why this is happening and so wanted to better understand before I took that route.

***Below is code for the R Console version:***

```
library(tidyverse)
library(EpiNow2)
library(tools)
library(zoo)


# Paths for output files (used as reference for Daily Dashboard and other reports)
# ok_rt_output <-  '/Users/tony/Dropbox/Chickasaw R Queries/ok_rt_output.rds'
# cn_rt_output <-  '/Users/tony/Dropbox/Chickasaw R Queries/cn_rt_output.rds'
# cn_counties_rt_output <-  '/Users/tony/Dropbox/Chickasaw R Queries/cn_counties_output'


# Define defaults for generation time, incubation period and reporting delay for COVID19.

generation_time <- get_generation_time(disease = "SARS-CoV-2", source = "ganyani")
incubation_period <- get_incubation_period(disease = "SARS-CoV-2", source = "lauer")


#set number of cores to use
options(mc.cores = ifelse(interactive(), 4, 1))
# construct example distributions
generation_time <- get_generation_time(disease = "SARS-CoV-2", source = "ganyani")
incubation_period <- get_incubation_period(disease = "SARS-CoV-2", source = "lauer")



# Reporting Delay 
reporting_delay <- list(mean = convert_to_logmean(3, 1), 
                        mean_sd = 0.1,
                        sd = convert_to_logsd(3, 1), 
                        sd_sd = 0.1, 
                        max = 10)



# Obtain data from JHU Repository

jhu_county_COVID_confirmed <- read_csv("https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/raw/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_confirmed_US.csv", na="")

# Put dates into a single column
jhu_county_COVID_confirmed_data <- jhu_county_COVID_confirmed %>% select(c(-UID, -iso2, -iso3, -code3, -FIPS, -Lat, -Long_, -Combined_Key, -Country_Region, County=Admin2))
jhu_county_COVID_confirmed_data <- jhu_county_COVID_confirmed_data %>% pivot_longer(c(-County, -Province_State), names_to = "Date", values_to = "Cases")
jhu_county_COVID_confirmed_data$Date <- strptime(trimws(jhu_county_COVID_confirmed_data$Date), format='%m/%d/%y')
jhu_county_COVID_confirmed_data$Date <- as.Date(jhu_county_COVID_confirmed_data$Date)

# Limit to Oklahoma
ok_jhu_county_COVID_confirmed <- jhu_county_COVID_confirmed_data %>% filter(Province_State=='Oklahoma')
ok_jhu_county_COVID_confirmed <- ok_jhu_county_COVID_confirmed %>% rename(county=County, state=Province_State, date=Date, cases_total=Cases)
ok_jhu_county_COVID_confirmed <- ok_jhu_county_COVID_confirmed %>% select(state, county, date, cases_total)



# Add in VERY latest OK data from OK DoH.

# Download latest day of *Oklahoma* COVID data.  Defines fields as needed.
ok_covid_data_latest_for_daily_dashboard <- read_csv("https://storage.googleapis.com/ok-covid-gcs-public-download/oklahoma_cases_county.csv", na="")
ok_covid_data_latest_for_daily_dashboard$ReportDate <- as.Date(ok_covid_data_latest_for_daily_dashboard$ReportDate)
ok_covid_data_latest_for_daily_dashboard$County <- as.factor((ok_covid_data_latest_for_daily_dashboard$County))

# Adjust format from state data (counties are in all caps at first; so make them lower case and then adjust the "Mc" counties)
ok_covid_data_latest_for_daily_dashboard <- mutate(ok_covid_data_latest_for_daily_dashboard, County = toTitleCase(tolower(`County`)))
ok_covid_data_latest_for_daily_dashboard$County[ok_covid_data_latest_for_daily_dashboard$County == "Mccurtain"] <- "McCurtain"
ok_covid_data_latest_for_daily_dashboard$County[ok_covid_data_latest_for_daily_dashboard$County == "Mcclain"] <- "McClain"
ok_covid_data_latest_for_daily_dashboard$County[ok_covid_data_latest_for_daily_dashboard$County == "Mcintosh"] <- "McIntosh"
ok_covid_data_latest_for_daily_dashboard <- ok_covid_data_latest_for_daily_dashboard %>% rename(`Date`=`ReportDate`)
ok_covid_data_latest_for_daily_dashboard <- ok_covid_data_latest_for_daily_dashboard %>% rename(`Recoveries`=`Recovered`)
ok_covid_data_latest_for_daily_dashboard$Province_State <- "Oklahoma"
ok_covid_data_latest_for_daily_dashboard <- ok_covid_data_latest_for_daily_dashboard[,c("County", "Province_State", "Date", "Cases", "Deaths")]

ok_latest_day_for_daily_dashboard <- ok_covid_data_latest_for_daily_dashboard %>% group_by(Province_State, County, Date) %>% summarise(OK_Cases=sum(Cases))

ok_latest_day_for_daily_dashboard <- ok_latest_day_for_daily_dashboard %>% rename(cases_total=OK_Cases, date=Date, county=County, state=Province_State) 

  

# Append latest data file for Oklahoma to existing COVID (after first testing it is in fact new)

if(min(ok_latest_day_for_daily_dashboard$date) > max(ok_jhu_county_COVID_confirmed$date)) {ok_cases_by_day <- rbind(ok_jhu_county_COVID_confirmed, ok_latest_day_for_daily_dashboard) }
if(min(ok_latest_day_for_daily_dashboard$date) <= max(ok_jhu_county_COVID_confirmed$date)) {ok_cases_by_day <- ok_jhu_county_COVID_confirmed}


# Oklahoma Cases by Day
ok_cases_by_day <- ok_cases_by_day %>% arrange(state, county, date)

# New Cases in Oklahoma for Rt calculation
ok_cases_by_day_for_Rt <- ok_cases_by_day %>% group_by(date) %>% summarise(OK_Cases = sum(cases_total, na.rm = TRUE))

ok_cases_by_day_for_Rt <- ok_cases_by_day_for_Rt %>% mutate(OK_New_Cases=OK_Cases - lag(OK_Cases,1)) 
ok_cases_by_day_for_Rt <- ok_cases_by_day_for_Rt %>% select(-OK_Cases) %>% rename(confirm=OK_New_Cases)
# Limit cases to dates from 1 April
ok_cases_by_day_for_Rt <- ok_cases_by_day_for_Rt %>% filter(date >= '2020-04-01')

# estimate Rt and nowcast/forecast cases by date of infection for Oklahoma
out_ok <- epinow(reported_cases = ok_cases_by_day_for_Rt, generation_time = generation_time,
              rt = rt_opts(prior = list(mean = 1, sd = 0.2)),  # replace earlier mean of 2 and sd of 0.1 used in initial approach by Abbott et al.
              delays = delay_opts(incubation_period, reporting_delay), return_output = TRUE, 
              verbose = TRUE, horizon=14)
# summary of the latest estimates
summary(out_ok)     
# plot estimates          
plot(out_ok)
```

***Below is code for the R Markdown version of this query***

````
```
---
title: "Rt Sample"
output:
  word_document: default
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, collapse = TRUE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE)

library(tidyverse)
library(zoo)
library(readxl)
library(tools)
library(EpiNow2)
```

## R Markdown

This is a query that graphs the transmission rate of COVID19 in the American state of Oklahoma.  It uses the EpiNow2 package to do this.  

More info can be found on epiforecasts.io



``` {r ok_rt_chart}
# Note this is a sample report so the commentary (e.g., progress) will appear in the report.

generation_time <- get_generation_time(disease = "SARS-CoV-2", source = "ganyani")
incubation_period <- get_incubation_period(disease = "SARS-CoV-2", source = "lauer")


#set number of cores to use
options(mc.cores = ifelse(interactive(), 4, 1))
# construct example distributions
generation_time <- get_generation_time(disease = "SARS-CoV-2", source = "ganyani")
incubation_period <- get_incubation_period(disease = "SARS-CoV-2", source = "lauer")



# Reporting Delay 
reporting_delay <- list(mean = convert_to_logmean(3, 1), 
                        mean_sd = 0.1,
                        sd = convert_to_logsd(3, 1), 
                        sd_sd = 0.1, 
                        max = 10)



# Obtain data from JHU Repository

jhu_county_COVID_confirmed <- read_csv("https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/raw/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_confirmed_US.csv", na="")

# Put dates into a single column
jhu_county_COVID_confirmed_data <- jhu_county_COVID_confirmed %>% select(c(-UID, -iso2, -iso3, -code3, -FIPS, -Lat, -Long_, -Combined_Key, -Country_Region, County=Admin2))
jhu_county_COVID_confirmed_data <- jhu_county_COVID_confirmed_data %>% pivot_longer(c(-County, -Province_State), names_to = "Date", values_to = "Cases")
jhu_county_COVID_confirmed_data$Date <- strptime(trimws(jhu_county_COVID_confirmed_data$Date), format='%m/%d/%y')
jhu_county_COVID_confirmed_data$Date <- as.Date(jhu_county_COVID_confirmed_data$Date)

# Limit to Oklahoma
ok_jhu_county_COVID_confirmed <- jhu_county_COVID_confirmed_data %>% filter(Province_State=='Oklahoma')
ok_jhu_county_COVID_confirmed <- ok_jhu_county_COVID_confirmed %>% rename(county=County, state=Province_State, date=Date, cases_total=Cases)
ok_jhu_county_COVID_confirmed <- ok_jhu_county_COVID_confirmed %>% select(state, county, date, cases_total)



# Add in VERY latest OK data from OK DoH.

# Download latest day of *Oklahoma* COVID data.  Defines fields as needed.
ok_covid_data_latest_for_daily_dashboard <- read_csv("https://storage.googleapis.com/ok-covid-gcs-public-download/oklahoma_cases_county.csv", na="")
ok_covid_data_latest_for_daily_dashboard$ReportDate <- as.Date(ok_covid_data_latest_for_daily_dashboard$ReportDate)
ok_covid_data_latest_for_daily_dashboard$County <- as.factor((ok_covid_data_latest_for_daily_dashboard$County))

# Adjust format from state data (counties are in all caps at first; so make them lower case and then adjust the "Mc" counties)
ok_covid_data_latest_for_daily_dashboard <- mutate(ok_covid_data_latest_for_daily_dashboard, County = toTitleCase(tolower(`County`)))
ok_covid_data_latest_for_daily_dashboard$County[ok_covid_data_latest_for_daily_dashboard$County == "Mccurtain"] <- "McCurtain"
ok_covid_data_latest_for_daily_dashboard$County[ok_covid_data_latest_for_daily_dashboard$County == "Mcclain"] <- "McClain"
ok_covid_data_latest_for_daily_dashboard$County[ok_covid_data_latest_for_daily_dashboard$County == "Mcintosh"] <- "McIntosh"
ok_covid_data_latest_for_daily_dashboard <- ok_covid_data_latest_for_daily_dashboard %>% rename(`Date`=`ReportDate`)
ok_covid_data_latest_for_daily_dashboard <- ok_covid_data_latest_for_daily_dashboard %>% rename(`Recoveries`=`Recovered`)
ok_covid_data_latest_for_daily_dashboard$Province_State <- "Oklahoma"
ok_covid_data_latest_for_daily_dashboard <- ok_covid_data_latest_for_daily_dashboard[,c("County", "Province_State", "Date", "Cases", "Deaths")]

ok_latest_day_for_daily_dashboard <- ok_covid_data_latest_for_daily_dashboard %>% group_by(Province_State, County, Date) %>% summarise(OK_Cases=sum(Cases))

ok_latest_day_for_daily_dashboard <- ok_latest_day_for_daily_dashboard %>% rename(cases_total=OK_Cases, date=Date, county=County, state=Province_State) 

  

# Append latest data file for Oklahoma to existing COVID (after first testing it is in fact new)

if(min(ok_latest_day_for_daily_dashboard$date) > max(ok_jhu_county_COVID_confirmed$date)) {ok_cases_by_day <- rbind(ok_jhu_county_COVID_confirmed, ok_latest_day_for_daily_dashboard) }
if(min(ok_latest_day_for_daily_dashboard$date) <= max(ok_jhu_county_COVID_confirmed$date)) {ok_cases_by_day <- ok_jhu_county_COVID_confirmed}


# Oklahoma Cases by Day
ok_cases_by_day <- ok_cases_by_day %>% arrange(state, county, date)

# New Cases in Oklahoma for Rt calculation
ok_cases_by_day_for_Rt <- ok_cases_by_day %>% group_by(date) %>% summarise(OK_Cases = sum(cases_total, na.rm = TRUE))

ok_cases_by_day_for_Rt <- ok_cases_by_day_for_Rt %>% mutate(OK_New_Cases=OK_Cases - lag(OK_Cases,1)) 
ok_cases_by_day_for_Rt <- ok_cases_by_day_for_Rt %>% select(-OK_Cases) %>% rename(confirm=OK_New_Cases)
# Limit cases to dates from 1 April
ok_cases_by_day_for_Rt <- ok_cases_by_day_for_Rt %>% filter(date >= '2020-04-01')

# estimate Rt and nowcast/forecast cases by date of infection for Oklahoma
out_ok <- epinow(reported_cases = ok_cases_by_day_for_Rt, generation_time = generation_time,
              rt = rt_opts(prior = list(mean = 1, sd = 0.2)),  # replace earlier mean of 2 and sd of 0.1 used in initial approach by Abbott et al.
              delays = delay_opts(incubation_period, reporting_delay), return_output = TRUE, 
              verbose = TRUE, horizon=14)

summary(out_ok)

plot(out_ok)
````

Comment: @T PERRY is this solved ? I met the same question . Thanks!

Comment: Hi, unfortunately it isn't!  I ended up having to write two queries -- one to do the analysis I needed, and the other to create the R Markdown report (importing the data from the first query).  It isn't ideal -- but it is working.

I'd love to know why RMarkdown makes things run so much more slowly.  Perhaps it can be fixed in a newer version?

Comment: Got it, maybe your way is the best method currently .Thanks !